# change apache to apache+nginx .htaccess ruls

Tags: nginx

how to convert it .htaccess ruls to apache+nginx as proxy reverse

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 8080
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywsite.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```